# PHPMailer return success but email never got to my inbox

Tags: php, phpmailer, mail-sender

I'm using PHPMailer 5.2.28 and apparently it send the email (I'm getting the sucess page), but when I check my mail I'm not receiving it.

I've uploaded PHPMailer files on host and even then got nothing (i'm using kinghost).

My send.php code is

```
    <?php

require dirname(__FILE__) . '/inc/variaveisFixas.php';
require_once("envioForm/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$emailBase = $emailCliente;


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);


$mail->From = $_POST['email'];
$mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];


$mail->addAddress($emailBase);



$mail->addReplyTo($emailCliente, '');


$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject  = "Formulário de Contato";
 $mail->Body .= " Nome: ".$_POST['name']."\r\n";
 $mail->Body .= " E-mail: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
 $mail->Body .= " Telefone: ".$_POST['number']."\r\n";
 $mail->Body .= " Mensagem: ".nl2br($_POST['message'])."";

$enviado = $mail->Send();
 
 $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
 
 if ($enviado) {
    header('Location: http://homolog.meumarketing.net/programas/teste/?mensagemenviada#faleconosco');
 } else {
    header('Location: http://homolog.meumarketing.net/programas/teste/?error#faleconosco');
 }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You must check the logs of the SMTP server which relays your emails - Sendmail or Postfix or Qmail or whatever it is. These logs will tell you whether the message actually left your server or not.

Comment: Don't use PHPMailer 5.x; it's no longer supported. You don't need to call `isHTML()` when you have no HTML content. You don't need to call `clearAllRecipients` after sending either, as it's not doing anything useful. Like @IVOGELOV said though – you need to look at your mail server's logs.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I ended up changing to mail() 'cause my host took it better. ;)